# Using with UR option of DB2 in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2

I am looking for an example for using DB2 with UR option with JPA Repository of Spring Data JPA.

There is already a duplicate question with no answer on it.

"DB2 “With UR” Spring Data JPA"

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Maybe add defaultIsolationLevel=1 in your JDBC connection string? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052429.html

Comment: @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) I added this but this is still not appending the With UR when I see dumped hibernate queries

Comment: I would not necessarily expect `WITH UR` to the added to the query text, but that does not mean the statement is not running in uncommitted isolation

Comment: Try this monitor element to see the isolation level of a current connection or unit of work https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0060801.html

Comment: I am not sure how can I use this with Spring boot to find current Isolation level in dumped queries

Comment: Setting isolation level doesn't add with UR option. Was able to test it locally. Need to figure out other way

Answer (score 0):

You can see what isolation level a current connection, or current unit of work is using via some of the `MON` table functions. E.g.

```
db2 "select c.CURRENT_ISOLATION, c.APPLICATION_NAME from table(mon_get_connection(null,-2)) c"
```

which returns

```
CURRENT_ISOLATION APPLICATION_NAME      
----------------- ----------------------
                  db2jcc_application    
                  db2jcc_application    
                  db2jcc_application    
                  db2bp                 
UR                db2bp                 
                  db2jcc_application    

  6 record(s) selected.
```

or

```
select CURRENT_ISOLATION, APPLICATION_HANDLE from table(mon_get_unit_of_work(null,-2,null)) c
```

which returns e.g.

```
CURRENT_ISOLATION APPLICATION_HANDLE  
----------------- --------------------
                                   394
                                   393
                                   392
                                   477
UR                                 555
                                   395

  6 record(s) selected.
```

Both table functions can return lots of other columns too

Comment: Is it possible to do it via Spring while query is running? AT least what I know I dont have access to these tables

Comment: If you don’t have permissions on those then I guess not. If you have set isolation at the connection or session level the special variables CURRENT ISOLATION will show you your current isolation level https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010945.html

Comment: P.S. why do you want to use UR anyway

Comment: This is an old, but good article that includes other ways to see your effective isolation level https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1107db2isolationlevel/index.html

Comment: Use of UR option is somehow legacy stuff. Will go through article.

Comment: Setting isolation level doesnt add with UR option. Was able to test it locally. Need to figure out other way